# How do I display json to textviews?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm trying to display some json data to textviews. My "getTitle" getter method works fine and the data is shown in the textview widget. However when I should pass the "getDescription" getter method, it doesn't comes up for suggestion.
I would really love some help with this, or also if I'm not going about it the right way someone could point me in the right direction.

```
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Campaign>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Campaign> call, Response<Campaign> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String id = response.body().getId();
                campaignName.setText(getTitle());
                campaignDesc.setText();


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(StartSurveyActivity.this, "Error Retrieving Id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Campaign> call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here if request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my java campaign model class. Also I thought it was important to mention that my "getDescription" getter and setter is shown in a pale greyish color while the "getTitle" getter and setter is the gold looking color. Thanks for your assistance in advance.

```
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public Boolean getDeleted() {
    return deleted;
}

public void setDeleted(Boolean deleted) {
    this.deleted = deleted;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getSurveyUrl() {
    return surveyUrl;
}

public void setSurveyUrl(String surveyUrl) {
    this.surveyUrl = surveyUrl;
}

public Integer getTotalResponseCount() {
    return totalResponseCount;
}

public void setTotalResponseCount(Integer totalResponseCount) {
    this.totalResponseCount = totalResponseCount;
}

public String getLanguageCode() {
    return languageCode;
}

public void setLanguageCode(String languageCode) {
    this.languageCode = languageCode;
}
public List<Question> getQuestions() {
    return questions;
}

public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
    this.questions = questions;
}

public Date getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Date created) {
    this.created = created;
}

public String getOrganisationLogoUrl() {
    return organisationLogoUrl;
}

public void setOrganisationLogoUrl(String organisationLogoUrl) {
    this.organisationLogoUrl = organisationLogoUrl;
}

public String getOrganisationName() {
    return organisationName;
}

public void setOrganisationName(String organisationName) {
    this.organisationName = organisationName;
}
```

Comment: where is your textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below, you are calling method on response

```
campaignName.setText(response.body().getDescription())
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I also realized that the data that was been shown by my "getTitle" getter method prior to your answer wasn't actually the right one. So respect bro

Answer (score 0):

The body of the response will hold the data or response object you have defined. So to call any getter or setter method of the response object you have to use body of the response for example response.body().getDescription(), response.body().getCreated(). To show description in the TextView try this

`campaignDesc.setText(response.body().getDescription())`